# Google Search Console Crawl 404 linked Error from strange Website

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, robots.txt, 404, crawl-errors

Image:
[image: Strange Webiste]

The error is displayed because the URL has added the symbol ; at the end.

```
/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/iuiuiuiuiuiui.pdf;  (incorrect)
```

If we remove the symbol ; the URL it works normally.

```
/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/iuiuiuiuiuiui.pdf  (correct)
```

This is for all the .pdf files I have on my site. About a hundred 404 crawl errors have occurred from this site. (http://aparser.docme.ru/results/paperzz/18w24/week-eldocz.txt)
Does anyone know what this site is?
I also noticed that Website contains too many sites.

How do I fix these 404 crawl errors?

Comment: *How do I fix these 404 crawl errors?* I would not bother. 404 errors cause no harm. In this case, this is not an error to be fixed. There is nothing wrong with your site. Leave it alone. Just because some trash site creates bad links to your site does not mean it is your problem. It is theirs. Cheers!!

Answer (score -2):

It's better to remove the URL.

Go to webmaster tools then click google index then remove URL

Comment: The URL does not exist. This is precisely the point. Hense the 404. So there is no url to remove. Cheers!!